# Within a directive, why is it necessary to wrap .focus() in $timeout or $evalAsync in order to work?

Tags: angularjs

In the code below, I cannot simply call "element[0].focus()" but instead need to wrap this in either $timeout or $evalAsync?

Full code and working example of the problem: http://plnkr.co/qW20iZ5D1tUpQ6gL6shZ?p=preview

```
app.setFocus = function ($timeout, $rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.setFocus, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue === true && newValue != oldValue) {
          var performWork = function() {
            element[0].focus();
            console.log(document.activeElement);
          };

          // Question: Why do I need to execute performWork()
          // any of the two commented out ways below
          // in order for this to work? Why does not just
          // calling performWork() work?
          //$timeout(performWork, 0);
          //$rootScope.$evalAsync(performWork);

          performWork();
        }
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Give your directive a priority > 0

```
app.setFocus = function ($timeout, $rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1,
```

The problem happens because `ngClass` manipulates the DOM element after you set the focus, and probably it's responsible for losing the focus.

#### How to solve it?

- You need `ngClass` $watch to run before your directive's $watch.
- postLinking functions runs in reversed order ( low -> high priority )
- $watches are invoked in the same order they are registered.
- `ngClass` has no priority ( defaults to 0)

So by giving a priority > 0 to your directive you assure that `ngClass` $watch is registered before your directive's $watch

have fun!

Comment: This works in the Plnkr... a few questions: (1) am I using a postLink function... thought it was just link? (2) Plnkr code was heavily pared down version of my application. In my full application, setting "priority: 99" does not work. What else could be going on?

Comment: @eb80 (1) the link function is actually a postLink function ( if you want a preLink function you need to return an object definition like `{ pre: fn }` (2) I need to see the code to know what happens

Comment: interesting that it does not work when we use ng-if for hiding logic, instead of ng-class, but works if we use ng-show